# Strange getting width of page in phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, screen-capture

here is the script code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.paperSize = {
  format: 'A4', 
  orientation: "landscape"
};

page.open('http://www.google.com', function () {

  var arr = page.evaluate(function () {
     var pageWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
     var pageHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

     return [pageWidth, pageHeight];
  });

  console.log('pagwWidth: ' + arr[0] + '; pageHeight: ' + arr[1]);

  page.render('google.pdf');
  phantom.exit();    
});
```

I'm trying to get clientWidth and clientHeight of document.body page. When I exec this script I'm getting the folowing values:

```
pagwWidth: 400; pageHeight: 484
```

Why is the width above is 400px? I think I should be wider.

---

Thank you for the reply. But then I don't understand the following thing. When I use viewportSize = {width: 1024, height: 800}

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.paperSize = {
  format: 'A4', 
  orientation: "landscape"
};

page.viewportSize = {width: 1024, height: 800};
page.open('http://www.google.com', function () {

  page.render('google.pdf');
  phantom.exit();    
});
```

I get the following file:
[image]

But if I use viewportSize = {width: 400, height: 400}

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.paperSize = {
  format: 'A4', 
  orientation: "landscape"
};

page.viewportSize = {width: 400, height: 400};
page.open('http://www.google.com', function () {

  page.render('google.pdf');
  phantom.exit();    
});
```

I get the same:
[image]

So I don't understand how does viewportSize affect to the view?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The document is affected by the viewport size and not by the paper size. Think along this line, how a web page looks like in your web browser has nothing to do with your current printer setting.

Use `viewportSize` if you want to influence the page layout:

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 800 };
```

Comment: This is now a different issue. The "printing" of a document (to a PDF file) forces a different layout, namely adjusted to the paper size. If you still dump the document width and height, they are still matched to the viewport.